# creating a excel chart that groups months by quarter

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a table that contains the last 12 months of sales data like this

```
+-------------+------------+-------------+
| December-19 | January-20 | February-20 | and so on
+-------------+------------+-------------+
|         999 |        999 |         999 |
|         999 |        999 |         999 |
|         999 |        999 |         999 |
+-------------+------------+-------------+
```

I need a bar chart that shows total sales per quarter. I can't make a seperate table because the column headers will change each month. I tried a pivot table but it won't allow grouping the months.

Comment: A quick solution would be to add another row to your schedule for quarter. You should then be able to get the pivot table group things by quarter. Hopefully, this help.

Comment: @BradR I would like to have the month names in the legend.

Comment: You should restructure the table so that "Month" is a column header and there is one row per month. Then you can put month as a dimension on the pivot table and in the legend (series) in the pivot chart.

Comment: Try to create a PivotChart with group date? https://excelchamps.com/blog/group-dates-in-a-pivot-table/